# bootstrap 3 html/css: Centering responsive text inside of responsive image (codepen file)

Tags: html, css, responsive

Here is my codepen document, I am trying to get the header text to stay centered in the header image when going to smaller window sizes; currently the text moves outside the frame: [codepen doc](https://codepen.io/Napolean/pen/amrdPo).

```css
.headerimg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  font-family:  Helvetica, sans-serif;
  z-index: 10;
  color: White;
  margin-top: -28em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6.15vw;
  #font-size: 63px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.125em;

}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  letter-spacing: 0.6em;
  margin-top: -0.2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
     <img class="full-width-div headerimg" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dez063exa/image/upload/v1477347105/AdobeStock_121279291_bqhwas.jpg" alt="Flower Image"> 
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 header text-center">
    <h1>Michael Blaney</h1>
    
    <h4>UX-DESIGNER</h4>
    </div>
```

I am new to coding but it seems like the header text does not see the image as its parent container, perhaps I did that incorrectly? Also am trying to get the menu button to be on the right side of the page not left (cannot seem to figure out how to do that; taking the absolute: position; away then creates problems for the header image staying on the top of the page).

Comment: To use a image as a background, see CSS background property.